# Adding activityindicator on Default image - code given

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an imaged name Default.png. This will load when the application is launching. Now i need to add an activity indicator to it. So it will spin and make the app look nice.

We know that we can't add any UI Components when the app is loading. So i thought to add the `UIActivityIndicator` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in the `App delegate`.

These are the steps i followed. 
i added a view
added the default.png
added activity indicator

then

```
[window addSubView:view];
```

But nothing hapence.

Help how to write the code for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you do need to add another `UIView` to your window (*not* another `UIViewContoller`, necessarily) temporarily. I do this sort of thing often. Here's some code that would be appropriate for your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:` method:

```
[window makeKeyAndVisible]
...

// Create and show an overlay view with a spinner
UIImage *defaultImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:defaultImage];
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
            initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
// Position the spinner appropriately for our splash image so it's not obscured
CGRect frame = spinner.frame;
frame.origin.x = imageView.frame.size.width / 2 - frame.size.width / 2;
frame.origin.y = imageView.frame.size.height / 5 * 4 - frame.size.height / 2;
spinner.frame = frame;
[spinner startAnimating];
[spinner setHidesWhenStopped:YES];

startupView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
[startupView addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
[startupView addSubview:spinner];
[spinner release];
[window addSubview:startupView];
```

The ivar `startupView` belongs to the app delegate, and later in the startup sequence another method removes it gracefully by fading it from view:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[startupView subviews] lastObject];
[spinner stopAnimating];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^(void) {
                     startupView.alpha = 0.0;
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [startupView removeFromSuperview];
                     [startupView release];
                 }];
```

It's worth mentioning that splash screens like this are not the "recommended" startup screen in Apple's view. But they do not seem to reject apps that have them.

Comment: Thanks, where should i add the removing activityindicator code (the 2nd part of your code). In which method should i include it ?

Comment: and what does [window makeKeyAndVisible]
 do ?

Comment: The code to remove the splash screen should be put whereever it is that you have completed your startup and initialization. For example, from `applicationDidFinishLaunching` you might call another method (or call it inside an async block) that does some initialization of your UI or loads some data. When that completes, you could then remove the splash. `makeKeyAndVisible` tells the window to make itself visible and to be on top of any other windows.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you wanna do a "custom splash screen" isnt it? 
You cannot add the activity indicator in this way! 
You need add a view controller, and at this view controller do stuff that you need with activity indicator!

Comment: From where do i call this ViewCOntroller From ? from which method

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions. at this method you set your SplashScreenViewController as self.window.rootViewController;

Comment: of course, you need create a new view controller call SplashScreenViewControlle

Comment: How do i remove it? is it applicationDidBecomeActive ?

Comment: I tried adding as you mentioned `SplashScreenViewController*splashScreenViewController =[SplashScreenViewController  alloc]]initWithNibName:@"SplashScreenViewController " bundle:nil; self.window.rootViewController=SplashScreenViewController `. But i don't see the activity indicator. WOnder if its hapenning very fast. If so how could i make it to be there for 2 seconds.